# How to replicate from Standby mode database

Tags: sql-server, replication, restore

I have set up a pipeline which brings transactional logs each hour from a FTP site, and this newly created database is in **Standby** mode all the time because I need to read data during an office hour.

Initially, I was thinking about leaving the restore mode in **NoRecovery** because I learned that Standby mode takes more time and for performance reason. But then, I realized that I cannot read data during an office hour, so I decided to set up hourly transaction log update in **Standby** mode all the time.

So, I will have one database which I am trying to isolate it to just pull transactional logs hourly, and then I would like to have a copy of this database so that it would not interrupt any process (of hourly logging) while I am reading data for reporting purposes.

**I am trying to see if there is a way to replicate this database (which is in standby mode) so that at least I have a backup database, and I could pull data from there for reporting purposes.**

Or would it be better if the database that update logging files daily from FTP site be **NoRecovery** mode and there is a way to replicate this database somehow? I am just thinking about a better option to set up stable database architecure.

BTW, this particular SQL Server is in an Azure VM, and  I am trying to bring in only necessary data into Azure SQL Server (Portal) eventually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to see if there is a way to replicate this database (which is in standby mode) so that at least I have a backup database, and I could pull data from there for reporting purposes.

You can always restore two separate databases from the log backups, one in NoRecovery and one in Standby.

Comment: I ended up just replicating two StandBy modes (just for back up), not restoring in NoRecovery because I found no point of having NoRecovery since I would have to read data. I created a separate question here since my issue is not resolved. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/292194/schedule-replicating-database-from-standby-mode-to-recovery-mode?noredirect=1#comment571786_292194

Answer (score 2):

Any reason you can't just use the native **Replication** features of SQL Server, such as [Transactional Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/replication-transactional-overview)?

You can real-time synchronize between your two servers, and then reporting off the **Subscriber server** won't affect performance of the **Publisher server.**

You can also look into **Snapshot Replication** if you want something less real-time and more scheduled on a recurring basis.

Comment: I think Snapshot Replication is what I am looking into. But it appears that Publisher database cannot be Standby mode. It has to be Recovery mode, right?

Comment: @Java Correct that Standby mode doesn't work with **replication**. I believe you'll need to bring it out of **Standby mode** by executing a command such as `RESTORE DATABASE YourDatabaseName WITH RECOVERY;` first. From your second post, I understand now that your first database is being **log shipped**. I don't believe you'll be able to use **Standby mode** so long as you're using **replication**.